# How to combine 2 array to an Object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 arrays which are the same length like this:

```
$scope.access_name = ['group1','group2','group3','group4']

access_value=[1,2,1,3]
```

How can I combine to have result like this:

```
object_access = {'group1:1','group2:2','group3:1','group4:3'}
```

thankyou very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var object_access={};
for(int i=0;i<access_value.length;i++)
{
  object_access[$scope.access_name[i]]=access_value[i];
}
```